# What OS can I install on my second HD?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-installation

I have 1 computer with HD, unfortunately, I can't install OS on it by usb or CD. Also I have a second working PC. I've connect a Hard Disk to him. What Operation System I can install on this Hard Disk that the other computer load it?

Comment: You need to re-write this as it’s not really understandable. Why can’t you install an O/S one drive but another? What is it you want to end up with as a result?

Comment: I want that my second PC works with the HD with O/S have been installed from (on) other PC.

Comment: Well if it’s Windows and not encrypted you can insert it into the other PC but you may find that due to the TPM (Trusted Platform Module) you’ll not be able to boot it on some occasions, assuming it’s Windows...

Comment: Why can't your computer install an OS using USB or CD? Is it broken, too old or what? All PCs made in the last 10 years can boot off USB, and all PCs since about 1995 can boot from CDROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like:

- your first computer can't boot an installer off of USB or a CD-ROM
- you have a second computer that can, and want to install an OS there, and then switch the hard drive with the installed OS to the first system.

You can likely pull this off with little to no issue with Linux (i.e. Ubuntu), as long as both systems have hardware supported, especially if the hard drive interface is the same on both systems (SATA, most likely).  You may have to do some tweaking of the kernel command line if you do something weird or RAID is involved.

With Windows, it's a little more tricky, but possible.  The one thing that will be a certain show stopper are disk controller drivers, which would be an issue with things like Intel's IRRT or RAID.  So make sure no special storage options are enabled in the BIOS of both systems, and try to make sure you are using the same type of hard drive interface on both systems.  You should also run Sysprep on the second computer before moving it to the first computer.  When Windows boots on the first computer, it will go through the OOBE prompts and set up properly.  You may need to hunt down drivers for hardware that is on the first system that is not on the second system.